# Oracle 18c XE- How to split string into numbers

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring

I'm trying to split string into numbers. String looks like this:

```
POINT(-122.419956922531 37.7647100858191)
```

I'd like to remove 'Point' and paranthesis' and get only numbers. I tried this (code below). Even though it looks good in the table I keep on failing to convert results into numbers:

```sql
select 
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(geom_, '(\S*)' ) as longi,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(geom_, '(\S*)[^()]',1,2) as atti    
from 
   (select 
      a.*,
      REGEXP_SUBSTR('POINT(-122.419956922531 37.7647100858191)', '\d.+') as geom_ from dual a);
```

Any tips on how to extract numbers from `POINT(-122.419956922531 37.7647100858191)`?

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         geom_,
         'POINT\(([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?) ([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)\)',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS longitude,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         geom_,
         'POINT\(([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?) ([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)\)',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         3
       ) AS latitude
FROM   your_table;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( geom_, '[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 1 ) AS longitude,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( geom_, '[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 2 ) AS latitude
FROM   your_table;
```

or with simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( geom_, 7, INSTR( geom_, ' ' ) - 7 )
         AS longitude,
       SUBSTR( geom_, INSTR( geom_, ' ' ) + 1, LENGTH( geom_ ) - INSTR( geom_, ' ' ) - 1 )
         AS latitide
FROM   your_table
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( geom_ ) AS
SELECT 'POINT(-122.419956922531 37.7647100858191)' FROM DUAL;
```

All of them output:

> ```
> LONGITUDE         | LATITUDE        
> :---------------- | :---------------
> -122.419956922531 | 37.7647100858191
> ```

*(Note: Wrap the output in `TO_NUMBER` if you want a number rather than a string containing a numeric value.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=de6d94486553b5f159d048f2a596fb85)*

---

## Update:

If your decimal separator is normally `,` then you can use `TO_NUMBER` and explicitly specify a `.` decimal separator as the third argument when using `TO_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT TO_NUMBER(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( geom_, '[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 1 ),
         '999D9999999999999',
         'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'''
       ) AS longitude,
       TO_NUMBER(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( geom_, '[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 2 ),
         '999D9999999999999',
         'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'''
       ) AS latitude
FROM ( select 'POINT(-122.419956922531 37.7647100858191)' as geom_ from dual );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0cf61f9405f79682ffac889707bb79c7)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this:select 
        TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR( geom_, '[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 1 )) AS longitude,
        TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR( geom_, '[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 2 )) AS latitude
from 
   (select 
      a.*,
      REGEXP_SUBSTR('POINT(-122.419956922531 37.7647100858191)', '\d.+') as geom_ from dual a)
but i get error:
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: @Qualculus_90 Don't use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in the inner sub-query. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=027fffcb4fab81ae4e91846912a2dd3d)

Comment: For some reason it does not work on my Oracle 18c XE. Used the same code as in your fiddle which is:
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR( geom_, '[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 1 )) AS longitude,
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR( geom_, '[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 2 )) AS latitude
FROM   (
  select 'POINT(-122.419956922531 37.7647100858191)' as geom_ from dual
);
ERROR:
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: Ok worked just fine. I had to replace '.' with ','.
Thanks

Comment: @Qualculus_90 Added an update for if your decimal separator in numbers is shown as a comma (`,`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward way to do it:

```
WITH cteString
       AS (SELECT 'POINT(-122.419956922531 37.7647100858191)' AS POINT_STRING FROM DUAL)
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(POINT_STRING, '[+-]?[0-9.]+', 1, 1)) AS LATITUDE,
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(POINT_STRING, '[+-]?[0-9.]+', 1, 2)) AS LONGITUDE
  FROM cteString
```

The regular expression `[+-]?[0-9.]+` accepts substrings consisting of the one or more digits 0-9 and the decimal point, optionally preceded by a sign character. It looks for the first such substring, converts the resulting substring to a NUMBER, and puts it into the result set as a field called LATITUDE. It then looks for the second such substring, converts it to NUMBER, and calls the LONGITUDE.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=485a0d5e5749503adf522a894e124ad5)

Comment: It may be a simpler regular expression but it would match invalid numeric strings (i.e. `....` or `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: Test-driven development. OP has provided a (admittedly minimal) set of test data. This code processes the given test data correctly - therefore, it fills all requirements given. Should OP care to provide additional test data for which the above code does *not* work then changes can be made - but until then this works Just Fine. :-)